# How to Create model.graphdef and config.pbtxt of a trained model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

In order to serve a model in triton Inference server, the model repository should look like below

```
  <model-repository-path>/
        <model-name>/
          config.pbtxt
          1/
            model.graphdef
```

But I am stuck at creating the above repository.

After you trained a model in TensorFlow,

```
        1)How do you create model.graphdef?

        2)how do you create config.pbtxt?
```

Answer (score 3):

'model.graphdef' is your trained tensorflow model, it will have the extension .pb. When you train a model in tensorflow the weights are saved as a pb file. You can add that to this folder.

In this case you do not need to create a config.pbtxt file because triton inference server can automatically generate the configurations from tensorflow, tensorRT and ONNX models. You can simply start the server with the command --strict-model-config = false and it will generate the config.pbtxt file for you.

If you do wish to create your own config.pbtxt you can do so as well. The details are available in the official triton documentation.

Comment: is there a way that we can see the generated config.pbtxt file of the triton inferencing server?

Answer (score 0):

The auto generated config file can be viewed using

`curl localhost:8000/v2/models/<model_name>/config | jq`

Use information from this output to create your own config file